# How to call a method with parameters inside another method?

Tags: java, class, oop, methods

How do you call a method with parameters inside another method?

For example, I am trying to call my `likes()` method inside my `goFishingIn()` method but it's not compiling. Here's my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Fisher   
{
  public void keep(Fish fish) 
  {
    if(this.numFishCaught < LIMIT)
    {
      fishesCaught.add(fish);
      numFishCaught++;
    }
  }

  public boolean likes(Fish fish)
  {
    if(fish.size >= this.keepSize && fish.species != "Sunfish")
    {
      return true;
    }
    else 
    {
      return false;
    }
  }

  public void goFishingIn(Pond pond)
  {
    pond.catchAFish();
    this.likes(Fish fish);
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you do invoke your `goFishinIn` method? How do you use `System.out.println(..)`?

Comment: You need a `Fish fish` instance to pass as parameter. Probably `pond.catchAFish` returns a `Fish`, then you can pass this object reference as parameter.

Comment: Make an object of Fish first then pass it likes inside     goFishingIn(Pond pond)

Comment: You have a problem with `fish.species != "Sunfish"`  should be instead `! fish.species.equals("Sunfish")` See more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what it looks like, you should be able to change your `goFishingIn()` method like so:

```
public void goFishingIn(Pond pond)
{
  Fish fish = pond.catchAFish();
  this.likes(fish);
}
```

Basically, you just need to pass an instance of `fish` to the `likes()` method, so you need to instantiate the `fish` prior to calling the `likes()` method.

Or, you could even shorten it up and call the `catchAFish()` method from inside the parameter, if you do not need to do anything with the `fish` afterwards.

```
public void goFishingIn(Pond pond)
{
  this.likes(pond.catchAFish());
}
```

The first method would be preferable though, as it will allow you to make any future references to the `fish` object.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  If you are satisfied with the answer, go ahead and like/accept it so that we know you have solved your question.

Answer (score 1):

if you already have a `fish` somewhere, you'd call it like so

```
this.likes(fish);
```

If you don't, maybe you have to make one

```
Fish fish = new Fish();
this.likes(fish);
```

or pass one in, or do whatever to get one in scope

```
public void goFishingIn(Pond pond, Fish fish)
{
  pond.catchAFish();
  this.likes(fish);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are declaring a method, you state parameters with classes, such as

```
public void goFishingIn(Pond pond)
```

but when you invoke a method, you only pass a variable, there is no Class identifier.

```
this.likes(Fish fish);
```

should be

```
this.likes(fish);
```

However `fish` variable is not defined anywhere inside `goFishingIn()` method body, therefore you will get an error that it's undefined. You need to obtain the `fish` value somewhere, or define it.

It seems to me that most reasonable in this case would be to make `pond.catchAFish()` return type `Fish` and then store the return value in `fish` variable.

```
Fish fish = pond.catchAFish();
```

Then you will be able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You should change

```
   this.likes(Fish fish);
```

into

```
this.likes(fish);
```

When you pass arguments to a method , you dont specify the type.
You only specify the type in the method signature itself. Nog when you call this method.